# Overload bracket operator assign

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a problem figuring out to use the [] operator to assign a value, i have 2 different errors,

"binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'double' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

no operator "=" matches these operands.

Am I missing something here?

Header

```
 Class CMyVector{
 public:
 double operator[](const int index) const;
 double & operator[](const int index);
 CMyVector operator+(const CMyVector mv1);
 }
```

cpp

```
double CMyVector::operator[](const int index) const
{
    return arr[index];
}

double & CMyVector::operator[](const int index)
{
    return arr[index];
}

CMyVector CMyVector::operator+(const CMyVector mv1)
{
    CMyVector *retval = new CMyVector();

    retval[0] = arr[i] + mv1[i];

    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CMyVector::operator+` seems weird.

1.`retval` is a pointer, (i.e. `CMyVector *`), then `retval[i]` will be `CMyVector`, which doesn't make sense for `retval[i] = arr[i] + mv1[i];`. You might mean `(*retval)[i] = arr[i] + mv1[i];`. BTW: Here's a memory leak because you didn't `delete` the pointer.

2.You `new` a pointer `retval`, and then set value on it, at last return `*this`? It doesn't make sense. You might mean:

```
CMyVector CMyVector::operator+(const CMyVector& mv1)
{
    CMyVector retval;
    for (int i = 0;i < dim;i++)
    {
         retval[i] = arr[i] + mv1[i];
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CMyVector CMyVector::operator+(const CMyVector mv1)
{
    CMyVector *retval = new CMyVector();
    for (int i = 0;i < dim;i++)
    {
         retval[i] = arr[i] + mv1[i];
    }
    return *this;
}
```

There are a few issues with this function:

1. You shouldn't dynamically allocate a `CMyVector` in order to return by value; that just leaks memory and incurs unnecessary cost. It should just be `CMyVector retval;`.
2. Since `retval` is a pointer, `retval[i]` is trying to subscript it like an array. You would want `(*retval)[i]`, but since we got rid of the dynamic allocation above, you can just do `retval[i]`.
3. You return `*this` instead of `*retval`. This should now be `return retval;`.
4. You should take your argument by-reference to avoid the copy.
5. `operator+` is generally best implemented as a non-member function so that the arguments are treated symmetrically.

The fixed code:

```
CMyVector operator+(const CMyVector& lhs, const CMyVector& rhs)
{
    CMyVector retval;
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    {
         retval[i] = lhs[i] + rhs[i];
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, but i just used *this as mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: @JoachimGotzes That has a completely different meaning and won't give you what you want. Note that Joachim has deleted that bit from his answer, he likely assumed you were implementing `operator+=` instead or something.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but i still worked if i state vec = vec2 * 2; i have the correct values withing vec.

Answer (score 1):

In the addition operator function, `retval` is a *pointer*, which means you must dereference it to use the operator "inline":

```
(*retval)[i] = ...
```

Or you could call the operator function explicitly using the "arrow" operator (which does the dereferencing for you):

```
retval->operator[](i) = ...
```

*However* the variable should *not* be a pointer, since it's the *value* you should return, which means your operator function is flawed in that it will give you a memory leak *and* not return the correct value.

See e.g. [this operator overloading reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Binary_arithmetic_operators) for an example on how to implement it.